# What would the regular expression be in ruby for this input

Tags: ruby, regex

So the input will be of the form

> 2, 0: dl 18.6496954092342,0.011123208182191

and I have the regex

```
m=/^(\d+),(\d+): ([urdl])? ((\d+.\d+))*[,]*((\d+.\d+))*[,]*((\d+.\d+))*[,]*((\d+.\d+))*/
```

No matter what I try the [urdl] part will match everything that is a word character it is only suppose to match the letters u, r, d, or l which can be in any order as many times as they want (including 0 times)
How can I change this so it will not match things like  uxr

Thank you in advance for all your help I have been banging my head against a wall for over a day now

Comment: Maybe you should put the question mark inside the parentheses: ([urdl]?), but overall I don't get your question, here it doesn't match every word character.

Comment: Which part is confusing to you I will clear it up as best I can

Comment: Also I tried moving the ? around to no anvil

Comment: What you are effectively saying is that you've applied a regex to a string, a certain part of it isn't working, and you want to know how to fix it.  That's difficult to answer without knowing what you are trying to do. We could possibly figure that out by studying your regex, but that shouldn't be necessary. You should explain what you want to achieve, without reference to the regex, and then show both your actual and desired results for the example and regex you've given. Please do so with an edit, rather than elaborating in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I have built a regex for your [here](http://regexr.com/39igp). The regular expression would look like below. I'm not clear on he requirements, but you can clean it up as per your needs.

```
/^(?:\d+,\s*\d+:)\s*(?:[urdl]*)\s*(?:(?:\d+.\d+),?){1,3}$/g
```